# what is this compound CSS selector means?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
 .btnBlue.btnLtBlue
```

Does it mean an element who has both classes? `btnBlue` AND `btnLtBlue`

Answer (score 8):

Yes. When two class name are concatenated like that it means the element must have both classes for that rule to be applied